# opencv sgbm custom min max disparity per pixel

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, stereo-3d

I want to use sgbm to compute disparity but rather than setting global parameters of min and max disparity I want to have does values per pixel (so each pixel will have its own range where to search).
I know that sgbm from the opencv does not support that so I have to change its source code a bit. I am not quite into the details of the implementation, I know however that they use dynamic programming to solve it.

```
for( int d = minD; d < maxD; d++ )
            {
                int v = prow2[width-x-1 + d];
                int v0 = buffer[width-x-1 + d];
                int v1 = buffer[width-x-1 + d + width2];
                int c0 = std::max(0, u - v1); c0 = std::max(c0, v0 - u);
                int c1 = std::max(0, v - u1); c1 = std::max(c1, u0 - v);

                cost[x*D + d] = (CostType)(cost[x*D+d] + (std::min(c0, c1) >> diff_scale));
            }
```

This is the code sample from the source.cpp 
https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/modules/calib3d/src/stereosgbm.cpp between lines 240 and 250. 
Is it enough to change minD and maxD here with the values for the current pixel X. I am not sure if that will mess up the calculations. If someone has experience with this source code I would appreciate the help.

Comment: Good luck if you're trying to change OpenCV's source code. Do you want a custom range because you're using pyramids?

Comment: yes that is exactly the purpose. I want to use the pyramid to compute disparity and I need to change the source code but I am not sure if the change I've posted is enough.

Comment: It seems good to me although you will have to recompile all OpenCV to see if it works. Let me know if you have updates.